# Function does not get called and script exits

Tags: bash, scripting, exit

So i got the function `RM_OBJ_P` which gets called from the menu page `PAGE_RM`.  This is working, you can enter all the funky filenames you know and if they are in the database, the output gets printed to a text file (just as i want it to be). But if i ever foolishly choose the somehow "magical" option `x` (or `X`) which should call `PAGE_RM`, the script exits. What have i done wrong?
(I also tried to achieve this by using `return 0` instead of `PAGE_RM`)

EDIT: Obviously entering `x`as choice also calls `RM_P_*` (see added log)

```
RM_OBJ_P() {
echo "After you have finished, you can find the file here: $ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt"
echo
if [ ! -f file.txt ] ; then
    read -p "Please enter the name of the file you'd like to check (or x to return): " CHOICE
    case "$CHOICE" in
        *) RM_P_N ;;
        x|X) PAGE_RM ;;
    esac
else
    read -p "Please enter the name of the file you'd like to check: " CHOICE
    echo "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" >>$ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt
    echo "If you want to remove $CHOICE, please consider this:" >>$ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt
    case "$CHOICE" in
        *) RM_P_E;;
        x|X) PAGE_RM ;;
    esac
fi
}
```

In case it matters, `RM_P_N` and `RM_P_E`are both like this (and work as intended)

```
RM_P_*() {
echo "something gets an echo echo echo o o o" >file.txt
PATH/TO/perl_script.pl "$CHOICE" database_query >>file.txt
RM_OBJ_P
}
```

and last but not least, `PAGE_RM`

```
PAGE_RM() {
    clear
    while :; do
        PRINT_BANNER_S
        PRINT_RM_MENU
        echo "single - view"
        echo "print  - print"
        PRINT_LINE
        echo "x      - go back"
        PRINT_LINE3
        read -p "CHOICE: " CHOICE
            case "$CHOICE" in
                s|S) RM_OBJ ;;
                p|P) RM_OBJ_P ;;
                x|X) return 0
                PRINT_LINE
            esac
    done
}
```

Here the relevant part of the log

```
+ RM_OBJ_P
+ echo 'After you have finished, you can find the file here: DB_45763/remove.txt'
+ echo
+ '[' '!' -f DB_45763/remove.txt ']'
+ read -p 'Please enter the name of the file you'\''d like to check: ' CHOICE
Please enter the name of the file you'd like to check: + echo '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'
+ echo 'If you want to remove x, please consider this:'
+ case "$CHOICE" in
+ RM_P_E
+ echo 'If you want to remove x, please consider this:'
+ ./files/perls/remove_object.pl x dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.sqlite '' ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it this way
[nice example of think before you (speak) ask].
If anyone has a better solution, feel free to answer

```
RM_OBJ_P() {
echo "After you have finished, you can find the file here: $ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt"
echo
if [ ! -f $ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt ] ; then
    read -p "Please enter the name of the file you'd like to check (x to abort): " CHOICE
    if [[ $CHOICE = x ]] ; then
        PAGE_RM
    else
        RM_P_N
    fi
else
    read -p "Please enter the name of the file you'd like to check (x to abort): " CHOICE
    echo "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" >>$ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt
    echo "If you want to remove $CHOICE, please consider this:" >>$ACTIVE_DB/remove.txt
    if [[ $CHOICE = x ]] ; then
        PAGE_RM
    else
        RM_P_E
   fi
fi
}
```